# How to send notification to user whenever data updates[Flutter]?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm calling RESFUL NODE API from flutter to get some data on providing email and password to the server and it is working perfect. I am not storing this data on any database as I am scraping it from somewhere within my api and sending it back to user. Now I want to notify user whenever the data changes. All I am struggling is that how to know if, that comes in the form of JSON, changed or not because my api returns data in different order no matter it changes or not, due to asynchronous behavior. So how can I notify my user when data changes? Here is my flutter app code:

```
class UserPage extends StatefulWidget{
  Map formData;
  UserPage(formData){
      this.formData = formData;
  }
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _UserPageState();
  }
}

class _UserPageState extends State<UserPage> {
  List AssignmentData;
  List<dynamic> newData;
  String LoginFailedMsg ='';
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  void ValidateResponse() async{
    await http.post("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Accept' : 'application/json'
        },
        body: widget.formData
    ).then((response){
        if(response.statusCode == 200){
          // Login Successful
          setState(() {
              Fluttertoast.showToast(
                  msg: "Assignments Refreshed",
                  toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                  gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                  timeInSecForIos: 1
              );
              AssignmentData  = json.decode(response.body);

          });
        }
        else{
          //Login Failed
          setState(() {
            LoginFailedMsg = response.body;
            print(LoginFailedMsg);
          });
        }
    });
  }
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    ValidateResponse();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var android = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcer');
    var ios = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initSettings = new InitializationSettings(android, ios);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSettings,onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
  }
  Future onSelectNotification(String payload){
    debugPrint('payload:$payload');
    showDialog(context: context,builder: (_)=>
    new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Notification'),
        content: new Text('$payload')
    )
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    final AssignmentImage = Image.asset('assets/assignment_img.png',fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,);

    return new Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: Text('Pending Assignments'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
              color: Colors.black,
              tooltip: 'Refresh Assignments',
              onPressed: ValidateResponse,
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: new Column(
        children: <Widget> [Text(LoginFailedMsg),
          new Expanded(child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: AssignmentData == null ? 0 : AssignmentData.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) {
                return new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[SizedBox(height: 15,),
                        Text(
                            AssignmentData[index]['course'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                            ),
                        ),
                SizedBox(height: 15,),
                new ListView.builder(
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: AssignmentData[index]['pending_assignment'].length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int NoOfAssignments){
                            return new Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                    border: new Border.all(color: Colors.white12),
                                  color: Colors.white,

                                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black,blurRadius:4.0, ),]
                                ),
                            child: new Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                    'Name: '+AssignmentData[index]['pending_assignment'][NoOfAssignments]['name'],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                                    ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                Text(
                                    'Due Date: '+AssignmentData[index]['pending_assignment'][NoOfAssignments]['dueDate'],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                                    ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  elevation: 6,
                                child: Text(
                                  'Link: Open it',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
                                  ),
                                ),
                                  onPressed: () => LauncUrl(AssignmentData[index]['pending_assignment'][NoOfAssignments]['assignmentLink']).launchURL(),
                                )
                              ]

                            )
                            );
                          }
                )
                      ]
                );
              })
          )
        ]
    )
    );

}
}
```

Note: I have only initialized notification and not using it anywhere.